# GridView On select button : get value from selected row,redirect user to another page,use the value in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simple gridview and SqlData source to bind data table to gridview.

My question is :
On "Select" button from the gridview . I would like get a value from a column of current selected row then redirect the user to another page and execute a Sql Select command with the value taken .

I know how to get the value but I don't know how should I redirect the user and the value to the other page and execute the sql statment with the value taken.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do `Respose.Redirect(url);` and attach value in querystring that will work for you ..

```
i.e Response.Redirect("xyz.aspx?selectedValue = " + selectedvalue);
```

on redirected page get the selected value from querystring `Request.QueryString["selectedValue"]`  but before doing this make sure that Querystring variable is not null.

**or**

if the information is sensitive you dont want user to see it than make use of `Session` variable and than do `Response.Redirect(url);`

```
Session["SelectedValue"] = SelectValue;
Respose.Redirect(url);
```

on redirected page get the selected value from querystring `string s = Session["SelectedValue"].ToString()`   but before doing this make sure that session variable is not null.

Comment: ok thank you , I will test right now and I'll tell you if it worked

Comment: ok it worked , but the problem is that if I want to navigate to the "redirected" page without selecting from gridview , the code is always executing. I want to make it work only on Gridview selection .

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server"
    ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="X-Small">
<Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="YouFieldNameForText" DataNavigateUrlFields="YouFieldNameForValue" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="YourURL.aspx?YourValue={0}"
        HeaderText="header text" Target="_self" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```